# Elastic Search - how to use language analyzer with UTF-8 filter?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a problem with ElasticSearch language analyzer. I am working on Lithuanian language, so I am using Lithuanian language analyzer. Analyzer works fine and I got all word cases I need. For example, I index Lithuania city "Klaipėda":

```
PUT /cities/city/1
{
  "name": "Klaipėda"
}
```

Problem is that I also need to get a result, when I am searching "Klaipėda" only in Latin alphabet ("Klaipeda") and in all Lithuanian cases:

1. Nomanitive case: "Klaipeda"
2. Genitive case: "Klaipedos"
3. ...
4. Locative case: "Klaipedoje"

"Klaipėda", "Klaipėdos", "Klaipėdoje" - works, but "Klaipeda", "Klaipedos", "Klaipedoje" - not.

My index:

```
PUT /cities
{
  "mappings": {
    "city": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type":     "string",
          "analyzer": "lithuanian",
            "fields": {
              "folded": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "md_folded_analyzer"
             }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "md_folded_analyzer": {
            "type": "lithuanian",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter":  [ 
              "lowercase", 
              "asciifolding",
              "lithuanian_stop",
              "lithuanian_keywords",
              "lithuanian_stemmer"
            ]
          }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

and search query:

```
GET /cities/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "type":     "most_fields",
      "query":    "klaipeda", 
      "fields": [ "name", "name.folded" ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks for help.

Comment: Is it correct assumption that `lithuanian` stemmer doesn't do its best for all cases? If yes, then what actually could help you is lemmatizer (not stemmer) for Lithuanian language.

Comment: Actually I don't know how exactly lithuanian stemmer should work. On correct words it works fine. But problem is that many Lithuanians don't use Lithuanian alphabet in the internet. Instead of "Klaipėda", they write "Klaipeda", instead of "Žiežmariai", they write "Ziezmariai" and so on. From Lithuanian language perspective - it's a spelling mistake, so maybe lithuanian stemmer works how it should work (only on correct words). But I need to get a result even if user don't use Lithuanian alphabet. I think Russian lang has same problem - you can write: "дом", "дома", but also "dom", "doma".

Comment: Let's clarify: "Klaipėda" -> "Klaipeda" and "Žiežmariai" -> "Ziezmariai" is a pure `asciifolding` machinery. Whereas in Russian "дом" -> "dom" is something like translating cyrillic into latin alphabet. And I'm not sure whether it is frequent use-case - to support transliteral searches in Russian search engines :-) But it turns out I know how to help you here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique you are using here is so-called [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/multi-fields.html#multi-fields). The limitation of the underlying `name.folded` field is that you can't perform search against it - you can perform only sorting by `name.folded` and aggregation.

To make a way round this I've come up with the following set-up:

1. Separate fields set-up (to eliminate duplicates - just specify `copy_to`):

   ```
   curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/cities -d '
   {
     "mappings": {
       "city": {
         "properties": {
           "name": {
             "type":     "string",
             "analyzer": "lithuanian",
             "copy_to": "folded",
           },
           "folded": {
             "type": "string",
             "analyzer": "md_folded_analyzer"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }'
   ```
2. Change the type of your analyzer to `custom` as it described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#lithuanian-analyzer), because otherwise the `asciifolding` is not got into the config. And more important - `asciifolding` should go after all stemming / stop-words in Lithuanian language, because after folding the word can miss desired sense.

   ```
   curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/my_cities -d '
   {
     "settings": {
         "analysis": {
           "filter": {
             "lithuanian_stop": {
               "type":       "stop",
               "stopwords":  "_lithuanian_"
             },
             "lithuanian_stemmer": {
               "type":       "stemmer",
               "language":   "lithuanian"
             }
           },
           "analyzer": {
             "md_folded_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter":  [
                 "lowercase",
                 "lithuanian_stop",
                 "lithuanian_stemmer",
                 "asciifolding"
               ]
             }
           }
        }
     }
   }
   ```

   Sorry I've eliminated `lithuanian_keywords` - it requires additional set-up, which I missed here. But I hope you've got the idea.

Comment: No problem! Prašom! :)